# Can't find what's changing my title, how to override?

Tags: php, database, web, title

Currently my title is not what I set it to be in index.php

In index.php the title code is set to
 title1 
but whenever I refresh my site, it shows 'title1' for a brief second and it then updates and changes to 'title2' (if not obvious enough im using title1 and title2 as variables.) after looking through my code for nearly 45minutes and no luck, is there anyway to simply override the title2?

EDIT: If it means anything, this just randomly occured when connecting my VPS to the website, I have no idea why this happened.

Comment: show your code, no one can guess what could be wrong and how to help you with your problem.

Comment: @programmingArrow I'm not sure what to show, as I'm more looking for code, as the code isn't faulty, I just can't find what is changing the title. So when you go onto the site, it displays the correct title that I want it to be, but then within a split second, it goes to a different title, and I'm not sure what code is causing that or where it is, but I'm looking for a workaround that would almost override the other title

Comment: Is this happening to all pages of your site or only one?

Comment: @programmingArrow Well my site is only one page as of now, so only one.

Comment: Well its difficult to answer if your not going to put any of your code here and you haven't mentioned why are you using two different variables as title for a single page website

Comment: @programmingArrow Oh, I think I worded the part about not being obvious enough. When I said the title1 and 2 are variables, I meant that the title1 is actually called what I want the website to be called but I dont want to say what I'm calling it because It's a surprise for my friend.  And title2 is actually something else but that's what is being displayed in the title part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing; I thought you're talking about the HTML title of a page but then you mentioned PHP variables named $title1 and $title2. Can you show an example of what the problem code is?

-- UPDATE --

After reading your comment; PHP cannot manipulate HTML code. So what you could have going on, maybe there is a PHP variable in your title tag:

```
<title><?php echo $title1; ?></title>
```

In this case, the title variable may be getting manipulated somewhere else. What you could do (if you have PHP in the title tag) is somply remove the PHP and put a hardcoded title in.
If your title is changing and there ISN'T PHP code changing it, your problem could be javascript/jquery related, if you are working on a page that has a lot of javascript, something in there could be dynamically changing the title. I have a feeling this is what the problem is, because you said you notice that the title shows as one thing and then a split second later changes. You should do a find/search in your files to see if there is javascript manipulating the title tag.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. The example you showed was actually what some of the <title> tags said, it showed PHP. However, I did change all of the ones I saw, so that would lead me to believe that it is javascript/jquery related as there is a lot of js and jq in my page. How would I broadcast a find/search in all of my files to see if there is a title tag?

Comment: Thank you so much! After checking through the javascript and jquery, I found the issue that the title resorts back to default if the variable wasn't used, changed the default title and now all is well. Thanks again!